# Haciendo una prac me ha salido el siguiente error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double at

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programilla para aprender de una calculadora multifuncional y cuando he llegado a la ecuación de segundo grado me ha saltado el siguiente error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4445) at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2957) at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2911) at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2689) at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1209) at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1105) at pracCalculadora.Calculadora.main(Calculadora.java:93)"

La clase principal es la siguiente.

```java
package pracCalculadora;

import java.util.Scanner;

//Este es un programa que realiza una serie de calculos según cuales solicite el ususario y los números que introduzca.
public class Calculadora {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Entorno:
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
        Operaciones calculo=new Operaciones();
        int opcCalc;
        double num1;
        double num2;
        double num3;
        double resultado;
        double resultado2;
        char resp1;
        char respfinal;
        double acumulador=0;
        double contador=0;
            //Algoritmo:
        do {
        do {
            
        System.out.println("Las operaciones que puede hacer la  calculadora son las siguientes: \n"
                + "1-Sumar \n2-Restar \n3-Multiplicar \n4-Dividir \n5-Devolver el módulo de una división\n"
                + "6-Potencia de un número \n7-Media Aritmética \n8-Ecuación de Segundo Grado\n"
                + "9-Area y Longitud de un circulo");
        System.out.println("Indique que operación quiere hacer (Introduzca el número de la lista)");
         opcCalc=teclado.nextInt(); 
        }while(opcCalc<1 || opcCalc>9);
        
        
        if(opcCalc<=5 && opcCalc>=1) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca el primer número...");
            num1=teclado.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Introduzca el segundo número...");
            num2=teclado.nextDouble();
            if(opcCalc==1) {
                resultado=calculo.Suma(num1, num2);
                System.out.println("El resultado de la suma es: "+resultado);
            }else if(opcCalc==2) {
                resultado=calculo.Resta(num1, num2);
                System.out.println("El resultado de la resta es: "+resultado);
            }else if(opcCalc==3) {
                resultado=calculo.Producto(num1, num2);
                System.out.println("El resultado del producto es: "+resultado);
            }else if(opcCalc==4) {
                resultado=calculo.Division(num1, num2);
                System.out.println("El resultado de la división es: "+resultado);
            }else {
                resultado=calculo.Modulo(num1, num2);
                System.out.println("El resultado del modulo es: "+resultado);
            }
        }
        if(opcCalc==6) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca la base...");
            num1=teclado.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Introduzca el exponente...");
            num2=teclado.nextDouble();
            resultado=calculo.Potencia(num1, num2);
            System.out.println("El resultado de la potencia es: "+resultado);
        }else if(opcCalc==7) {
            do{
                System.out.println("Introduzca el primer número...");
                num1=teclado.nextDouble();
                contador=contador+1;
                acumulador=acumulador+num1;
                System.out.println("Quiere introducir otro número(s/n)");
                resp1=teclado.next().charAt(0);
            }while(resp1 =='s' || resp1=='S');
                resultado=calculo.Media(acumulador, contador);
                System.out.println("El resultado de la media es: "+resultado);
        }else if (opcCalc==8) {
            /*Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
            at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4445)
            at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2957)
            at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2911)
            at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2689)
            at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1209)
            at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1105)
            at pracCalculadora.Calculadora.main(Calculadora.java:81)
             */
            System.out.println("Introduzca a...");
            num1=teclado.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Introduzca b...");
            num2=teclado.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Introduzca c...");
            num3=teclado.nextDouble();
            resultado=calculo.Ecu2GrResult1(num1, num2, num3);
            resultado2=calculo.Ecu2GrResult2(num1, num2, num3);
            System.out.printf("%s\n%d\n%s\n%d\n","Los resultados de la ecuación de segundo grado son: ",resultado," y ",resultado2);
        }else if(opcCalc==9) {
            System.out.println("Introduzca el radio...");
            num1=teclado.nextDouble();
            resultado=calculo.Area(num1);
            resultado2=calculo.Longitud(num1);
            System.out.println("El area del circulo es: "+resultado+"\nLa longitud de la circunferencia es: "+resultado2);
            
        }
        System.out.println("¿Quiere realizar otra operación?(s/n)");
        respfinal=teclado.next().charAt(0);
        }while(respfinal=='s' || respfinal=='S');
        
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema está al mostrar los valores con ``printf``: %d es para enteros y tú quieres mostrar un double, entonces cambia ''%d'' por ``.2f`` que es para mostrar datos de tipo float o double.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias C: